# I have an uncorrect css path in the front-end html code

Tags: joomla, css

I am using CiviCRM 5.18.3.with Joomla! 3.9.12 and I can not solved a path problem within the html page where "/components/" should be replaced by "/administrator/components/" (see below). It works OK for the back-end but not for the front-end ??
Please, your help would be well appreciated. Tks.

> ...

Comment: Hi LMV welcome to civicrm stack exchange -  It looks like you might have tried to included something? that didn't attach properly? Can you add some more details about they problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Are the paths in the civicrm.settings.php files each pointing to the right place?

There's one for each of front and backend:
 - /components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
 - /administrator/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

If you just copy and past the paths that are set those two files (e.g. after a server migration) then you might get the error you currently have. But the paths in one file need to point to front-end Civi, and in the other point to back-end Civi (ie with /administrator appended).

Comment: Hi Nic. I renewed completely the installation with a fresh brand new joomla fully dedicated to civicrm (5.19.0). When I check the source code of my joomla civicrm front end I have for < link href="/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/crm-i.css?r=v61bI" rel="stylesheet" /> but it needs to get the "administrator/" appendice in front of this "href" to get the correct css file !! Could you please check any joomla front-end civicrm report and let me kno if the href to css files are correct on your side ? Thank you

Comment: Please for instance check the source code of this page and you will be able to notice that access to CSS files is incorrect (administrator/ is missing): https://projets.libertemontvalerien.org/index.php/civicrm